# Matplotlib Scatter and Histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, scatter-plot

I'm trying to plot some data using Matplotlib's 2d scatterplot function while at the same time, producing projected histograms on the x and y axes. The example I've found comes right from the matplotlib image gallery ([pylab_examples example code: scatter_hist.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_hist.html)).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter

# the random data
x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000)

nullfmt   = NullFormatter()         # no labels

# definitions for the axes
left, width = 0.1, 0.65
bottom, height = 0.1, 0.65
bottom_h = left_h = left+width+0.02

rect_scatter = [left, bottom, width, height]
rect_histx = [left, bottom_h, width, 0.2]
rect_histy = [left_h, bottom, 0.2, height]

# start with a rectangular Figure
plt.figure(1, figsize=(8,8))

axScatter = plt.axes(rect_scatter)
axHistx = plt.axes(rect_histx)
axHisty = plt.axes(rect_histy)

# no labels
axHistx.xaxis.set_major_formatter(nullfmt)
axHisty.yaxis.set_major_formatter(nullfmt)

# the scatter plot:
axScatter.scatter(x, y)

# now determine nice limits by hand:
binwidth = 0.25
xymax = np.max( [np.max(np.fabs(x)), np.max(np.fabs(y))] )
lim = ( int(xymax/binwidth) + 1) * binwidth

axScatter.set_xlim( (-lim, lim) )
axScatter.set_ylim( (-lim, lim) )

bins = np.arange(-lim, lim + binwidth, binwidth)

axHistx.hist(x, bins=bins)
axHisty.hist(y, bins=bins, orientation='horizontal')

axHistx.set_xlim( axScatter.get_xlim() )
axHisty.set_ylim( axScatter.get_ylim() )

plt.show()
```

The only problem is that the example doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
~$ python ~/Desktop/scatter_and_hist.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/scatter_and_hist.py", line 45, in <module>
    axHisty.hist(y, bins=bins, orientation='horizontal')
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 8180, in hist
    color=c, bottom=bottom)
TypeError: barh() got multiple values for keyword argument 'bottom'
```

I've gone through the code and isolated the problem.  It's line #45 (axHisty.hist(y, bins=bins, orientation='horizontal')) which is causing the problem. It's so frustrating to see the plot you want in their image library, but have the example not work. A second set of eyes would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code to the _minimum_ needed to reproduce the error and past the _full_ stack trace.

Comment: and what version of matplotlib are you using?  I think you have hit a bug.

Comment: I'll try to include less code next time. Most of it is necessary, just because I want people to see which bounds and which data I'm using. I'm using matplotlib version 1.2.1. The full stack trace is now included. Also, I've just tried this on my other computer with a default matplotlibrc file, and a non-anaconda packaged distribution, so neither of those seem to be the cause.

Comment: This code works fine in matplotlib 1.3.0

Comment: You have hit this https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1985 bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have hit a bug in v1.2.1 (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1985).  You can upgrade your matplotlib, monkey patch your version with the bug-fix, or use `np.histogram` and call `barh` with the correct order of arguments your self.

As a side note, the only code necessary for this question is:

```
x = np.random.rand(100)
plt.hist(x, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

everything else you posted is noise.

Comment: True, but that's only because you know that orientation='horizontal' was the culprit. If I knew that was the cause, I would have only posted the relevant code snippet. However, the likelihood that it was caused by me, the user, was much higher than it actually being a bug - hence my attempt at being comprehensive with my question asking. Thank you for the pointer, though. I'll give your suggestion a shot.

Comment: @astromax Sorry, I have had a stressful couple of days recently and am really cranky.

Comment: Don't worry - I didn't take it personally. I try to err on the side of more info rather than less, but I do agree that having to plow through lines of unnecessary code can be just as bad as not having enough to work with.

Comment: could you elaborate on `monkey patch your version with the bug-fix`?

Comment: @simona by monkey patch I mean copying the version of `hist` in that PR into your code and doing `matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist = patched_hist` or just using it as `patch_hist(ax, ...)`.  I would strongly suggest updating instead.